# Cant import local module

Tags: python, import, modulenotfounderror

So I am trying to use this repository on my computer but I cant seem to import a local module (Agent.pyx) and use functions from that file. The error I get is:
 `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RLAgent.Agent`
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0vvO.png)
[Link to repository](https://github.com/MehranTaghian/DQN-Trading)

Comment: Have you installed the ```keras-rl2 ``` package?

Comment: Yes I have double checked, and I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package manually

Comment: It's a file and I have it in my directory, what package must I install?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Agent.pyx` is a `.pyx` file, you will need to first build it. The README file in the linked repo also mentions this. So you need to move to the RLAgent directory and execute the setup instruction as:

```
cd RLAgent
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

This will build the required `.c` and `.so` file which will then enable it's import in other files such as `Train.py` which is where the import is throwing an error.

Comment: I've done this and I still get the same error under the Train file

Comment: Do you also have the `.so` file generated? Because in the screenshot I am only able to see the `Agent.c` file. Can you confirm that the `.so` file is also there, as with these two files present, I am able to load the Train file at my end.